How to set radio button values with dynamic values


<html>
      <body>
        <p>
          <p>I like red:
          <input type="radio" name="OptionChosen" id="100000000" value="yes" />
          Yes
          <input type="radio" name="OptionChosen" id="100000001" value="no" />
          No
          </p>
        </p>

        <p>
          <p>I Love Green:
          <input type="radio" name="OptionChosen" id="100000000" value="yes" />
          Yes
          <input type="radio" name="OptionChosen" id="100000001" value="no" />
          No
          </p>
        </p>
      </body>
 </html>



I need to create an HTML form with an option set, with options preselected just to display and convert to pdf
this list is in a different database with answers
I like red - yes (100000000)
I love green - No (100000001)
I am creating an HTML form with
how should I update this yes/ no by default?

Just a site not: An id must always be unique. In your example this is not the case. The radiobox element is designed to use as group with same name by browser.

Please use the checked attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

You need to match names and values
<p>
  I like red:
  <label><input type="radio" name="OptionChosenRed"  value="100000000" /> Yes</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="OptionChosenRed"  value="100000001" /> No</label>
</p>

<p>I Love Green:
  <label><input type="radio" name="OptionChosenGreen" value="100000000" /> Yes</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="OptionChosenGreen"  value="100000001" /> No</label>
</p>

will send
OptionChosenRed=100000000 (red yes) and
OptionChosenRed=100000001 (green no)
to the server.
Alternatively,
<p>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="OptionChosen"  value="100000000" />   I like red:</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="OptionChosen" value="200000000" /> I Love Green:</label>
</p>

will send OptionChosen=100000000,200000000 if they like both red and green and OptionChosen=200000000 if they only like green to the server upon submitting.

i have a external database with all the questions and answers. example - I like green - yes, i like red - no, i like blue - yes.
With these values, i am creating a html form, the form should look like
I like green
yes  No
I like red
yes   No
these yes no are radio button and these radio buttons are updated from the above database values

I understand, but your HTML needs to work, so perhaps the program that reads the response can save them correctly.
